# How do I Listen to Select2 Events in a Stimulus Controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, stimulusjs

I am trying to listen to a Select2 event in a Stimulus controller via the `data-action`.

I have a stimulus controller, where I have included an event listener for Select2 events, but I cannot listen for the Select2 event from the HTML.

```js
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
  initialize() {
    const $element = window.$(this.element);

    $element.select2({
    });

    $element.on('select2:select select2:unselect', (_event) => {
      this.element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    });
  }
}
```

I have to listen to the "change" event with the Stimulus `data-action` attribute, instead of "select2" events. The following code works. Listening via `data-action-"select2:select"` does not work.

```
<%= f.select :name, ['name1', 'name2'], data: {'controller' => 'select2'} %>
```

I would like to listen to events with the `data-action` attribute, as Stimulus is intended to be used.

Can I listen for Select2 events with Stimulus?

Comment: Without adding a wrapper, no. Stimulus only listens for standard DOM events. Where Select2 is an extension of jQuery, [`jQuery.trigger('select2:select');`](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/4.0.13/dist/js/select2.full.js#L2240), using [`jQuery.Event()`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). For an example on how to force jQuery to dispatch events to the DOM so Stimulus can listen for them see: [jQuery Event delegation](https://gist.github.com/kaspermeyer/7fe28bb7c55c2810e7b5f3d5e67c1a44). Then you could use `data-action="jquery:select2:select->controller#method"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the approach from https://psmy.medium.com/rails-6-stimulus-and-select2-de4a4d2b59e4

Make one incision into the connect() method of the controller that is responsible for capturing the select2 event and send it back out as a standard change event so that `'data-action': "change->controller#update"` will work as expected.

```js
import {Controller} from '@hotwired/stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["select"];
  
  connect() {
    $(this.selectTarget).on('select2:select', function () {
      let event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true }) // fire a native event
      this.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
  }

  update(event) {
    console.log("UPDATE");
  }
}
```

```html
<div data-controller="selector" >
  <select 'data-criteria-form-target': 'select',
          'data-action': "change->controller#update">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this approach but problem is that in update event I cannot read new value selected in dropdown, I just get nothing if I try $("#my_select_field").val()

Comment: @MiRo Works fine for me when I get the value with just plain Javascript using `event.currentTarget.value`.

Comment: You can get multiple values with: `$(event.currentTarget).val()`

Comment: For me `this.dispatchEvent(event)` its not working right now, i have to change for `this.selectTarget.dispatchEvent(event);`